# fast get value by byte-array key (something like "Dictionary<byte[16],int>")?

Tags: c#, dictionary, arrays, hashtable, binary-search-tree

In my programm i have very big(many-many terrabytes) stream of data as input, from which i need to get key - byte array(exacly 16 bytes - some pseudo-GUID), and by that key i need to get some other key - integer, and by that second key i need to do some calculations in memory. But i don't know how to get this "second key" really fast..

I can get all "byte[16] -> int" associations before start to work with this "very big stream of data". 
Dictionary seems to be pretty fast, but it don't work right with byte[16] as key - it's just check for object reference equality(in my sitiuation it will be always equal, because it's just buffer object), but i need use real byte-array values as key, and do this fast(every second counts)... How to do this?

Well... I'm already trying to implent own associative array class, based on binary search.. Or there any standart alternative to Dictionary, which can use something bigger than 4-byte int as key?

Comment: If you can show your code now, we can give some tips for improvements, but its not easy to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: what is that *stream* ? how does it presented to you ?

Comment: So, what's wrong with using `Guid`?

Comment: If computing speed is really important, ditch C#, use native (C/C++) language and store data in nice tree. Attempts to use generic types to solve this issue in C# will only make it slower.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , because of collisions, when using it as key.. Dictionary just use GetHashCode() Method of Guid Class. Whitch returns int - XOR of some little part of actual bytes from GUID.

In my case i found colission of Guid's GetHashCode() result just after about a half million itterations over "raw byte[16]->int array" data... But i can't have collisions! Data is verry important, because it's an financial data.

Comment: @rufanov So want to map 16-byte data to 4-byte key without collisions?

Comment: A dictionary will use `Guid`s `GetHashCode` *by default* but there's nothing to stop you passing a custom equality comparer. However, by the very nature of the fact that any `GetHashCode` implementation returns an `int`, there *will* be collisions.

Comment: @Tigran , One of tables from another company Data Warehouse(MS SQL Based)..  In which they have only one index - primary - on Date.. We can't do any grouping operations on data - query become super slow and expensive - most time server just kicks from itself because of memory overuse... 

So forward-only reading, and calculating on client-side seems to be only only posible solution i see.

Comment: @L.B , No :) I know, that is imposible :) But i don't know fast alternative in C# to Dictonary, which can provide fast "key-value" search, and can use key bigger than 4-byte int.

Comment: The purpose of the dictionary is to reduce the memory requirement at the cost of smallest possible additional time requirement. Don't worry about collisions now, in some theoretical sense. Get to practicalities, do some measurements, and only then decide if what you have is or is not good enough for you.

Comment: Also, when you say "I can't have collisions" this makes me think that you think that collisions will mess up your data, or data retrieval. This is not true. Collisions will increase the time of data retrieval (very tiny amount if they happen rarely), and will change nothing else.

Comment: @Dialecticus , hm? Is there some collision-handling implemented in standard .NET Dictionary class?

Comment: The term "collision" just means that two different keys are stored in the same bucket in a linked list. [Collisions are part of any dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution). Linked lists (or any other way of collision handling) are not desirable due to performance penalty, but they will not mess up the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the generic `Dictionary`, [you can supply your own `IEqualityComparer` comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132073%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can use this class to compare the keys.

This will get you started, performance can probably be optimized:

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<byte[]> {
    public bool Equals(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
        return a.SequenceEqual(b);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(byte[] key) {
        if (key == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        return key.Sum(b => b);
    }
}


// usage:

myDict = new Dictionary(myByteArray, myInt, new MyComparer());
```

Comment: Yes, i also found this constructor in my research. . Thanks. Currently i use it, with binary-search algorithm for equality comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could write some code to represent your type, as below.

```
public struct PseudoGuid : IReadOnlyList<byte>, IEquatable<PseudoGuid>
{
    private readonly byte[] value;

    public PseudoGuid(IList<byte> value)
    {
        if (value.Count != 16)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(...
        }

        this.value = value.ToArray();
    }

    public byte this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.value != null)
            {
                return this.value[index]
            }

            return default(byte);
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(PseudoGuid other)
    {
        return this.SequenceEquals(other);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder(32);
        for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            result.Append(this[i].ToString("X2"));
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return obj is PseudoGuid && this.Equals((PseudoGuid)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (this.value == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return BitConvertor.ToInt32(this.value, 0) ^
            BitConvertor.ToInt32(this.value, 4) ^
            BitConvertor.ToInt32(this.value, 8) ^
            BitConvertor.ToInt32(this.value, 12);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(PseudoGuid left, PseudoGuid right)
    {
        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(PseudoGuid left, PseudoGuid right)
    {
        return !left.Equals(right);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return 16;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<byte> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (this.value != null)
        {
            return ((IList<byte>)this.value).GetEnumerator();
        }

        return Enumerable.Repeat(default(byte), 16).GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator
             System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```